# How do I copy a file using terminal?

Tags: command-line, copy

My current directory is `~/Dropbox/RECENT` and I want to copy a file `input.txt` from my current directory to `~/Dropbox/RECENT/SORT` without deleting the original. And I want to copy `input.txt` with another name in my current directory.